# How to determine which drive Windows booted from?

Tags: windows, winapi

Is there an easy way of programmatically determining which drive the currently running Windows instance booted from? I am using Delphi, but any answer in just about any language/programming environment would be helpful.

Comment: Read env variable SystemDrive.

Comment: Please don't tag spam. If your question is language-agnostic, then don't add specific languages tags.

Comment: The `GetWindowsDirectory()` API function tells you the location of the current Windows instance.

Comment: *"which drive the currently running Windows instance booted from?"* - Which part of the boot process are you interested in?

Comment: @IInspectable Can you expand on this? I didn't know the drive could change mid-stream... I am actualy mostly interested having this info with the system fully booted and operational (which the other commenters covered) but I'd love to hear what other complications there are.

Comment: Booting into a system goes through several stages. It usually starts by executing the BIOS (or UEFI), then transfers control to the boot loader, that loads the OS. Each stage can run code stored on zero or more disk drives. If you're doing a PXE boot, for example, there is likely not even a single disk drive involved. In general, the question asked doesn't have an answer.